# Incremental score calculator Optaplanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to implement an `IncrementalScoreCalculator` for the current [Kaggle TSP challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/traveling-santa-2018-prime-paths/). So, I have been looking at the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#incrementalJavaScoreCalculation) and I have succesfully implemented an `EasyScoreCalacultor` that returns a `HardSoftScore` where the `hardscore` is the number of locations for which every 10th step is not a prime.

what I have looks as follows

```
 @Override
    public void beforeVariableChanged(Object o, String s) {
        if (o instanceof Domicile) {
            return;
        }
        switch (s) {
            case "previousStandstill":
                retract((Visit) o);
                break;
            case "position":
                retractPosition((Visit) o);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized variable change " + s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(Object o, String s) {
        if (o instanceof Domicile) {
            return;
        }

        switch (s) {
            case "previousStandstill":
                insert((Visit) o);
                break;
            case "position":
                insertPosition((Visit) o);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized variable change " + s);
        }
```

where `position` is a shadow variable.

`retractPosition` and `insertPosition` look as follows:

```
  private void retractPosition(Visit visit) {
        Integer position = visit.getPosition();
        if (position != null) {
            if (visit.getLocation().getId() % 10 == 0) {
                if (isPrime(position)) {
                    hardscore--;
                }

            } 
        }

    }

    private void insertPosition(Visit visit) {
        Integer position = visit.getPosition();
        if (position!= null) {

            if (visit.getLocation().getId() % 10 == 0) {
                if (isPrime(position)) {
                    hardscore++;
                } 
            } 
        }

    }
```

But this somehow does not seem to work correctly and I cannot seem to wrap my head around it. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: The `IncrementalScoreCalculator` and `shadow variables` don't combine well. One problem is that there are more before/after events than you'd except (due to chain correction of the chained planning variable). But the real problem is that the `before` methods for the shadow variable are called after the genuine variables changed. This is normally a good thing, but an `IncrementalScoreCalculator` hates it because it would like to know ALL entities that are going to change before ANY change (which is impossible by design).

ConstraintStreams (prototype in progress) are probably the solution.

Comment: I see, so the shadow variables are not updated yet when the `IncrementalScoreCalculator` is called. Thanks!

Comment: The IncrementalScoreCalculator also gets before/after calls caused by the shadow variables. However, the before's are the problem: they aren't predicted, so they happen when they happen - at which point the domain is in an intermediate state already for the incremental score calculator - driving the developer insane.

Comment: I think I understand - and yes it was driving me insane. However, how does this affect the VRPTW example from the [kiegroup github](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/score/VehicleRoutingIncrementalScoreCalculator.java) where `arrivalTime` is a shadow variable ? The calculation here seems rather straightforward. I mean arrival time and visit position are not that different from each other from a variable perspective, are they ? Both are variables for which the value depends on the predecessor.

Comment: That's a question that's bugging me too. By doing System.out on every score calculator call it should be possible to find out.

Comment: I am also trying to use `chained variables` in an `IncrementalScoreCalculator`.
Given the feedback on `shadow variables` we have removed them in favor of indexed caches that point to the beginning/end of each chain.
However, we understand that `before` / `after` methods are called on chain correction - is there any way to identify whether we are dealing with an intermediate or stable state?